# Need Help in getting respective value from a custom widget

Tags: flutter

I am a noob in flutter and i need help with this. So I made this counter widget where you can increase and decrease the counter value with button, and called that widget two times in my root widget. now I want to get respective counter value of those counter widget separately for each time I call my counter widget. How do I achieve that.

this is my main.dart file

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int count;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            CounterContainer(count, ValueKey(1)),
            Text('first counter : ${CounterContainer(count, ValueKey(1)).count}'),
            CounterContainer(count, ValueKey(2)),
            Text('second counter : ${CounterContainer(count, ValueKey(2)).count}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my Counter_widget

```
class CounterContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  int count;

  CounterContainer(this.count, ValueKey<int> valueKey);

  @override
  _CounterContainerState createState() => _CounterContainerState();
}

class _CounterContainerState extends State<CounterContainer> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      widget.count = ++_counter;

      print('------------>${widget.count}');
    });
  }

  void _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      if (_counter > 0) {
        widget.count = --_counter;
        print('------------>${widget.count}');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        Text('$_counter'),

        FlatButton(
          onPressed: _decrementCounter,
          child: Icon(Icons.remove),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can define two counters `counter1` and `counter2` and pass `callback` to do refresh

working demo

[image]

code snippet

```
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      ...
    });
    widget.callback();
  }

  void _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
     ...
    });
    widget.callback();
  }
  ...
  CounterContainer counter1;
  CounterContainer counter2;

  void refresh() {
    print("refresh");
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    counter1 = CounterContainer(count, ValueKey(1), refresh);
    counter2 = CounterContainer(count, ValueKey(2), refresh);
    super.initState();
  }
  ...
  children: <Widget>[
            counter1,
            Text('first counter : ${counter1.count}'),
            counter2,
            Text('second counter : ${counter2.count}'),
          ],
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CounterContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  int count;
  VoidCallback callback;

  CounterContainer(this.count, ValueKey<int> valueKey, this.callback);

  @override
  _CounterContainerState createState() => _CounterContainerState();
}

class _CounterContainerState extends State<CounterContainer> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      widget.count = ++_counter;

      print('------------>${widget.count}');
    });
    widget.callback();
  }

  void _decrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      if (_counter > 0) {
        widget.count = --_counter;
        print('------------>${widget.count}');
      }
    });
    widget.callback();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: _incrementCounter,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
        Text('$_counter'),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: _decrementCounter,
          child: Icon(Icons.remove),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int count;
  CounterContainer counter1;
  CounterContainer counter2;

  void refresh() {
    print("refresh");
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    counter1 = CounterContainer(count, ValueKey(1), refresh);
    counter2 = CounterContainer(count, ValueKey(2), refresh);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('${counter1.count}');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            counter1,
            Text('first counter : ${counter1.count}'),
            counter2,
            Text('second counter : ${counter2.count}'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```